# boolean and solidify problems

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, solidify-modifier

I want to make a lot of small square holes in the model.
The model has only a solid option. (the solid option is not applied on the a rectangular parallelepiped)
[image]

A boolean was used to create a hole in a model with a solid option.
However, as you can see in the picture below, a strange structure was created.
and also the hole did not made.
[image]

**How can I make a hole in the model?**
The pictures on the below are the model image that I want to make.
[image]

Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: You must activated the add-ons 'Bool tool'. Menu 'Edit/Preferences/Add-ons'. Look this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7LpZKCjF7k

Comment: Why would he have to activate bool tools? Correct me if I'm wrong but that just adds shortcuts for boolean modifier doesn't it?

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong, Jiří, but it also add a menu option in the object Menu call Bool Tool.

Comment: Actually, I've already activated the bool tool.
What options should I use in the Bool tool to resolve this issue?